# Multiple rabbitmq connections are open

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, .net-6.0

I am using C# and .NET6

I have configured rabbitMQ connection as SingleTon in program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddSingleTon<ConnectionFactory>(provider =>
{
    var configuration = provider.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
    var factory = new ConnectionFactory()
    {
        HostName = configuration.GetValue<string>("RabbitMQ:Server"),
        UserName = configuration.GetValue<string>("RabbitMQ:UserName"),
        Password = configuration.GetValue<string>("RabbitMQ:Password")
    };
    return factory;
});

builder.Services.AddScoped<IModel>(provider =>
{
    var factory = provider.GetService<ConnectionFactory>();
    var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
    var channel = connection.CreateModel();
    return channel;
});
```

Inside the controller I have

```
private readonly IModel _channel;
public MyController(IModel channel)
{
    _channel = channel;            
}
[HttpPost("sendmessage")]
public async Task SendMessageAsync([FromBody] model smppmessage)
{        
    _channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "smpp_queue", durable: false, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments: null);
    string message = JsonSerializer.Serialize(smppmessage);
    var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
    _channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "", routingKey: "smpp_queue", basicProperties: null, body: body);
}
```

**problem statement**
For each request, I see new connection is open in RabbitMQ, In some cases the connections are  reaching upto 0.1 million.

Can you please guide me where I am doing wrong. My requirement is to open single connection and use the same connection to send messages to RabbitMQ

Comment: Because of you added your IModel as scoped, for every request a new model is created. Inside your model, you create a new connection, which is provided by your singleton ConnectionFactory. So the behaviour you are observing, is aspected.

Comment: @TheTanic thanks for the reply, how do I solve this

Comment: I am not an expert in RabbitMQ, but you could try to add a connection itself as singleton instead of the factory, or override the ConnectionFactory to deliver only a single connection. But I can't tell you if this is best practice, or could lead to unexpected behaviour, like blocking messages